# Conjugacy in groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Regarding, conjugate classes I am confused and need help. It is one of the below, or the both:

i) It is w.r.t. the object (group) and the configuration achieved; or 
ii) it is for each individual action and the corresponding permutation.

I feel that it incorporates both (i) & (ii) above, i.e. it considers for making one set of symmetry (actions) to be equivalent to the other **iff** equivalence given by (ii) is satisfied, while one can substitute a given set of symmetry (actions) with a differing one if the actions result in same configuration of the object (or (i)).

My confusion arises from [here on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/234871/424260) that the set of diagonal reflections are different from edge reflections, for the case of even order of the group. $D_4$ has order in terms of number of symmetries (actions) as $8$, an even number and so should have difference between the two types of reflections.

=> So does the answer mean that the diagonal reflections are equivalent to each other? 
I am listing the permutations for $D_4$, induced by $R_{90}, D_{1,3}, D_{2,4}, D_x, D_y$, where $D_{1,3} =$ reflection across the diagonal joining vertices $1,3$; while for $D_y$ it is the reflection across the y-axis.

$R_{90} = (1 4 3 2)$

$D_{1,3} = (24)(1)(3)  $

$D_{2,4} = (13)(2)(4)$

$D_x = (14)(23)$

$D_y = (12)(34)$

But, all the 4 reflections are equivalent in one respect that need only two operations of the set of rotations, $R_i, 0\le i\le 3$ & any other single reflection to describe all other operations in terms of them.

So, how can I understand the concept of conjugacy is not clear to me.

<del>But have a doubt in my understanding of the above. It talks about order of $D_n$, as : "the dihedral group of order $n$, the set of symmetries of a regular $n-$gon". I feel that the order is : $8=(4+4)$, as there are 4 symmetries of reflections and 4 symmetries of rotations (including the identity one). This also stated [at this MSE question][2]. If so, then how it is satisfying the criteria of conjugacy? Am I interpreting the conjugacy wrong? My interpretation is that it refers to the final configuration of the vertices w.r.t. each other. From that respect, all four reflections produce the same orientation of the 4 vertices. I do not see it as in terms of individual actions' permutations, and hence differing permutations.</del>

Comment: Your notation is peculiar: you have given the same notation to four of your five permutations. Of course in $D_4$, diagonal reflections form one conjugacy class, while your "edge reflections" form a different conjugacy class.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown I hoped that all are equivalent except for which digit is placed before the other. I hoped you wanted a particular position's vertex number to be taken as the first one in each permutation. My doubt is still not addressed : how the theorem stated in the MSE answer is false.

Comment: Why a vote to close it? From where will I understand then?

Comment: Please help, it is confusing and difficult to google and to read for a novice like me.

Comment: Please somebody up-vote it, as there is otherwise a great chance of it being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D_4$ is, as you say, the group of euclidean symmetries of a square. One has to distinguish between this group of maps of the plane and the group of induced permutations of the vertices, which is a subgroup $D_4'$ of the symmetric group $S_4:={\cal S}\bigl(\{1,2,3,4\}\bigr)$.

In $D_4$ we have the $4$ rotations by $0^\circ$, $90^\circ$, $180^\circ$, and $-90^\circ$; all of these modulo $360^\circ$. Then there are two reflections across the two diagonals, and finally there are two reflections across symmetry axes parallel to the sides of the square.

$R_{180}$ and the reflections are of order $2$, hence their own inverses; furthermore $R_{-90}=R_{90}^{-1}$. By going through the motions one easily verifies that $D_{13}\circ R_{90}\circ D_{13}=R_{-90}$, hence $R_{90}$ and $R_{-90}$ are conjugate. Similarly $R_{-90}\circ D_{13}\circ R_{90}=D_{24}$ and $R_{-90}\circ D_x\circ R_{90}=D_y$. Finally $R_{180}$ is only conjugate to itself.

These "geometric" maps induce permutations of the vertices, which then can be studied in terms of cycle structure. Concerning conjugation one can say the following: Assume that $\pi$ is a permutation of some finite set $S$, and use $\sigma\in{\cal S}(S)$ for conjugating $\pi$ to another permutation $\pi':=\sigma\circ \pi\circ\sigma^{-1}$. If $\pi(a)=b$ then $\pi'\bigl(\sigma(a)\bigr)=\sigma(b)$. If in such a case $(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_r)$ is a cycle of $\pi$ then $\bigl(\sigma(a_1),\ldots,\sigma(a_r)\bigr)$ is a cycle of $\pi'$. It follows that $\pi$and $\pi'$ have the same cycle spectrum. If the full symmetric group is at stake then this argument can be reversed: If $\pi$ and $\pi'$ have the same cycle spectrum then they are conjugate in ${\cal S}(S)$.

In our example the permutation of $[4]$ induced by $R_{180}$ has the cycle decomposition $(13)(24)$, and the permutation induced by $D_x$ has the cycle decomposition $(14)(23)$. By the foregoing these two permutations are conjugate in $S_4$. But $R_{180}$ and $D_x$ are **not** conjugate in $D_4$; the reason being that $D_4'$ is only a proper subgroup  of $S_4$, and the $\sigma\in S_4$ used to conjugate between $(13)(24)$ and $(14)(23)$ does not lie in $D_4'$.

Comment: I agree, but I feel also that there is "no" case where the answer (as given in the hyperlink) of MSE satisfies the criteria for a dihedral group, as there would be always an even value for order of a dihedral group. Also, please elaborate (so that I don't make this again) why my 5 lines don't make any sense.

Comment: I am sorry for the notation for sets to be used, I have edited the OP. Also, I have seen now that the horizontal reflection is showing up as : $(14)(23)$, as the action of horizontal reflection would change the vertices that way. But, it also means that the similarity of the 4 reflections in terms of obtaining the same configuration of vertices cannot be shown by the permutations.

Comment: Please help, as there is modification done to OP to explain my problem with understanding conjugacy.

Comment: Thanks and am working on it for quite some time now. Although unable to grasp & am facing difficulties, but hope by enhancing the knowledge about the geometric view of group theory will be able to get it. Mainly the reason for this comment is to inform about possibly late developments in terms of asking questions on it, as it is taking its own time.