# What's the purpose/motivation of defining inner automorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, automorphism-group

My professor mentioned how it is a way to get from one subgroup to other subgroups. I see this with some of our book's examples (Contemporary Abstract Algebra, Gallian) but I feel like I am still missing the big picture, point, purpose, whatever you may call it. Any explanations appreciated

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11971/intuition-behind-conjugation-in-group-theory

Comment: (Edit: this is greatly expanded by Qiaochu's answer from the question that Snaw linked.) Note that if the group is a *matrix* group, then $A\mapsto PAP^{-1}$ is a "change of basis" operation. That is, the element and its image under conjugation describe "the same essential object, but viewed through a different lens" (formally: the same linear transformation, written in different bases)